# Nested if vs. if statement with two conditions behaves differently:

Tags: python, if-statement, nested-if

I have a dictionary `my_dict1`, which contains a key `'Error'` I also have another dictionary `my_dict2` that either has multiple keys, or is empty. I want to have an if statement that checks whether `my_dict1['Error']` is False and check if `my_dict2` has any content in it. The code is as follows:

```
my_dict1 = {'Error': False}
my_dict2 = {'somekey': True}

if my_dict1['Error'] == False:
    if len(my_dict2) > 0:
        print('ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

This code results in 'ok' as expected.

```
if my_dict1['Error'] == False & len(my_dict2)> 0:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

This results in 'no'. Am I understanding the & statement wrong?

Comment: `&` is not `and`. You here actually made an expression like `my_dict1['Error'] == (False & len(my_dict)) > 0`.

Comment: It's `and` and not `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error originates from the precedence of the operators. Your expression is equivalent to:

```
my_dict1['Error'] == (False & len(my_dict2)) > 0
```

Now since `False & 1` will result in `0`, since `False` acts as `0`, and the bitwise and-ing of `0` and `1` is `0`.

The expression `my_dict['Error'] == 0 > 0` is `False`. The `my_dict['Error'] == 0` will succeed, but `0 > 0` is of course `False`.

If you want to check two conditions, you should use the `and` operator, like:

```
if my_dict1['Error'] == False and len(my_dict2) > 0:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

or more *Pythonic*:

```
if not my_dict1['Error'] and my_dict2:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

The two are not entirely the same since `not my_dict['Error']` will succeed, given the *truthiness* of the corresponding value is `True`. If the items map on `bool`s, then the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I understanding the & statement wrong?

Unfortunately, yes I think so. `&` is bitwise AND, where logical AND is called `and` in Python.

For more information about the differences between logical and bitwise operators, see this page: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: That is not per se the problem, since `True & False`, etc. just act like a logical `and`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree. As you correctly point out in the comments, the problem seems to stem from operator precedence - that is your point, no? I quoted the part about `&` vs `and` since that is a common mistake as well :)